# Emoji edittext should return Unicode

Tags: android, unicode, emoji

I am working on Emoji.

I have used [this](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) library.

It works fine, But when i get text from the `EmojiconEditText` it do not returns me unicode which are used in that `edittext`.

As example If text is `I \ue32d emojicon` wher  \ue32d  is a heart icon.
 When use  `String Text=EmojiconEditText .gettext();` 
 it  should return the same text as `"I \ue32d emojicon"`

Please help me for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found solution.

You can get unicode from emoji by using `commons-lang-2.5 jar`

Check below code for emoji to unicode.

```
String textVal=edtpost.getText().toString();
String newval_unicode=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(textVal);
```

You can find uni code from this string.

May this answer help others.